# Script ou API para verificar se dominio está disponível em PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, domínio

Galera vocês conhecem algum script ou API que seja opensource que esteja funcionando em PHP para consultar se um domínio está disponível? Um que funcione para as extensões .com.br, procurei alguns mas até agora nada funcional, se tiver para CodeIgniter seria ótimo

Comment: Bom dia Carlos, só me deixa entender tu já tentou o WhoAPI.com? https://whoapi.com/documentation/code_examples

Comment: O Registro.br fornece uma API em JSON utilizando o link abaixo: https://rdap.registro.br/domain/dominioconsultado.com.br

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa necessariamente de uma API. Um simples `file_get_contents( )` pode resolver seu problema.

*Exemplo 1: está registrado o domínio teste555.com.br?*

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.whois.com/whois/teste555.com.br');
```

**Não**. Porquê? Porque foi encontrada a string `"No match for teste5555.com.br"` em `$content`, a variável que recebeu o retorno.

*Exemplo 2: está registrado o domínio google.com.br?*

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.whois.com/whois/google.com.br');
```

**Sim**, pois não foi encontrado `"No match for google.com.br"` em `$content.` E com `echo($content);` ainda se vê todas as informações do domínio. O Whois funciona para todos as extensões de países, creio eu, visto que sempre achei o que precisava.